# Get the highest value in database

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
    Dim elem As String
    elem = "College"
    Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    With conn
        .ConnectionString = ("SERVER=ANINGDZTS-PC;DATABASE=AEVS_2013;Trusted_Connection = yes;")
        .Open()
    End With

    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "SELECT [PositionID],[Position],[Partylist],[Department],[Fullname],[Lvl],[Section],[Votes] FROM tbl_Cand WHERE [Department] = '" & elem & "'"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandTimeout = 30
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    With DataGridView1
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True
        .DataSource = dt
    End With
    vvv()

    cmd.Dispose()
    cmd = Nothing
    conn.Dispose()
    conn = Nothing
```

This is my code to view all candidates, but I only want to get the name and votes of the person who has the highest accumulated votes. For example, in president, I have 2 candidates, but I only want to view who has the highest accumulated votes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you need to just modify sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to modify your sql statement to find the maximum value. Something like this should work:

```
   .CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 [PositionID],[Position],[Partylist],[Department],[Fullname],[Lvl],[Section],[Votes] FROM tbl_Cand WHERE [Department] = '" & elem & "'" ORDER BY [Votes] DESC
```

It select only one record (`TOP 1`) and orders the results by the Votes column so you will get the highest vote record.